# How do get the path of the file that the batch script was ran from?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

Ive added a batch script to my right click context menu of a .CXR file which is an image format. However when i right click and run the batch conversion script, It converts the entire folder. This is because the batch file has a loop in it that looks for all files of that filetype in the current folder.

How would i tell the batch file to use the file that it was ran from. i.e. The file i right clicked on?

EDIT: Ive included the code here. %~f1 works for passing the file but the output filename is showing "%%~df%%~pfPost_%%~nf.cxr" so im guessing theres something here i need to change too.

```
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    set editorArguments=

    if exist "%postprocessConfig%" (
        set editorArguments=!editorArguments! --config "%postprocessConfig%"
    )
    if exist "%lightMixConfig%" (
        set editorArguments=!editorArguments! --config "%lightMixConfig%"
    )
    set editorArguments=!editorArguments! --element "%inputElement%"

    set inputImage=%~f1
    set editorArguments=!editorArguments! "!inputImage!"
    set outputImage=%%~df%%~pfPost_%%~nf.%outputFormat%
    set editorArguments=!editorArguments! "!outputImage!"

    echo Processing !inputImage!
    "%editorExecutable%" !editorArguments!
```

Comment: %dp1, for the path, or %1 for the file. see `for /?`

Comment: `%%f` is never defined, so it's modifiers (`%%~df` etc.)  aren't either. (You probably meant `%%~d1` etc.)

Comment: @Stephan Ok thanks, Ive tried changing to d1 instead of df but the naming is still completely broken. The output file name is still just showing as  `%~d1%~p1Post_%~n1.cxr`

Comment: @Jpjapers, do not double up `%` for script argument variables e.g `%~dp1` is correct, `%%~dp1` is incorrect. If you double up when you are not supposed to, it will display literal `%` instead of the expanded value.

Comment: @michael_heath Perfect! Thanks i knew it would be something with the syntax. Thanks for your help!